# How to remove Html <li> bullets from codebehind?

Tags: javascript, css, html-lists, code-behind

I create an html list **from codebehind**, like this:

```
HtmlGenericControl list = new HtmlGenericControl("ul");
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
   HtmlGenericControl listItem = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
   Label textLabel = new Label();
   textLabel.Text = "Menu"+i;
   listItem.Controls.Add(textLabel);
   list.Controls.Add(listItem);
}
```

But the rendered list has bullets, and I want to prevent them.

Comment: What does the resulting HTML look like?

Comment: An html list with bullets :|

Comment: Specifically, does the `ul` get a class or an id? How about the `li`?

Comment: @a_maar do **not** edit to change the question.

Comment: @JeromyFrench Neither of them.

Comment: @Neal I didn't changed the question I just added more "problems" since I tested the supplied solution. Is this not recommended in SO? Should I approve this question and open another with the new issue?

Comment: @a_maar nope. not recommended. makes you look like a [help vampire](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19665/the-help-vampire-problem)

Comment: @Neal okey, so, do I approve an answer and open another question?

Comment: @a_maar all up to you. Or you can use the comments section of the answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you could use the style property:

```
list.Style.Add("list-style", "none");
```

Answer (score 21):

Use CSS:

```
ul {
   list-style: none;
}
```

Comment: The css solution works execellent because the bullet is off but I need to "recover" the space that was taken by the bullet.

Comment: @a_maar can you make an example of the rendered html/css on http://jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: @a_maar Then add padding to the `li` styling

Comment: I agree, this should be done in an external CSS rather than manipulating the HTML inline styles with codebehind.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you put an id name on the  like:
`HtmlGenericControl list = new HtmlGenericControl("ul");
list.Id = "myId";`

and then just define in the css:

```
#myId{
 list-style-type: none;
}
```

Comment: Classes should be used for styling not ID's (not invalid, just bad practice).